# wget download file to inurl directory

Tags: wget, curl, url

Is there any way to download file to inurl directory.

For example:
Here the url is https://url.com/api/discovery/manifest

I want the download structure be like

```
root_folder
- api
-- discovery
---- manifest
```

is there any command to automate this, I know I can enter the directory manually like
wget  -P api/discovery

Comment: If this is a Ubuntu question where is the server type and version number of the OS?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not the clearest, but here is my interpretation of it.

You want to take the filepath from the url
https://url.com/api/discovery/manifest

you can do that with (after the last . from /)

```
string='https://url.com/api/discovery/manifest' && fileloc=${string##*.} && fileloc='/'${fileloc#*/}
```

fileloc contains /api/discovery/manifest

To save to root you need sudo, it is better if you save it in your user home